# Implement Extended Jaccard Similairty in pdist MATLAB

Tags: matlab, pdist

I want to use `pdist()` in MATLAB and use a custom function "Extended Jaccard" defined as bellow:

```
 S_EJ(X_a, X_b) = (X_a . X_b) / (||X_a||^2 +  ||X_b||^2 - X_a . X_b)
```

where `X_a . X_b` represents the inner product between vectors `X_a` and `X_b` and || ||^2 is the norm_2 of a given vector.

It is strongly recommended to take advantage of `bsxfun()` as it is based on multi-threading. Ofcourse, if this is possible.

What do you think about:

```
  SEJ(x,y) = bsxfun(@(x, y) (x.*y)./(norm(x)^2 + norm(y)^2 - (x.*y)) , x, y);
```

Thanks for your opinions in advance.

Comment: so is this home work for us or for you? At least show us what you have tried and done so far please.

Comment: GameOfThrowns, of course it is not a homework. My only doubt was to use bsxfun() in a proper way. The function would like this :

    S_EJ = @(X_a,X_b)(bsxfun(xxxxxx,X_a,X_b))

Comment: I edited the question, please have a look :-)

Comment: Does the code you posted work? is it fast enough? what problem does that code has?

Answer (score 0):

Your function uses elementwise multiplication .* and division ./ which produces a vector output, not a number, which is expected.
You want the dot product and regular division.

**Assumming row vectors:**

```
ej_similarity = (vec1*vec2')/(norm(vec1)^2 + norm(vec2)^2 - vec1*vec2');
```

**Assuming column vectors:**

```
ej_similarity = (vec1'*vec2)/(norm(vec1)^2 + norm(vec2)^2 - vec1'*vec2);
```

**Generalized but a bit slower:**

```
ej_similarity = (dot(vec1, vec2)/(norm(vec1)^2 + norm(vec2)^2 - dot(vec1,vec2));
```